# initEvent is deprecated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that needs to be refactored using the latest alternative for initEvent:

```
let createdEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
createdEvent.initEvent(event);
document.dispatchEvent(createdEvent);
```

I tried the below way:

```
let createdEvent = new Event('Event', { "bubbles": true, "cancelable": false });
createdEvent.addEventListener(event);
document.dispatchEvent(createdEvent);
```

I am trying to add an event listener to an event. But it is not working. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: What is `event`?  It's not defined in this code.

Comment: ```event``` is basically a string value passed. Based on which the video player decides whether to pause the video or play it.

Comment: I don’t understand what the code is doing - is it trying to add an event listener to an event? What errors are you seeing in your browsers dev tools inspect facility console?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes,  it is trying to add an event listener to an event. I have updated the description as well.

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  In order to process events, the event needs to have a name.  The name you're using here is the literal value `"Event"`.  The variable `event` could be anything, and trying to add an event listener to the event itself makes no sense.  Try this instead: `document.addEventListener('Event', x => console.log("Event happened") )`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `addEventListener` must be the event name, and then a callback function.
Then your event listener must be attached to a DOM element (document or any node), not to the event object.

```js
let createdEvent = new Event('Event', { 
    "bubbles": true, 
    "cancelable": false 
}); 

someHtmlElement.addEventListener(
    "Event", 
    someEventHandlerCallback
); 

someHtmlElement.dispatchEvent(createdEvent);
```

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#example

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two implementations of an event dispatcher using deprecated [`createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)/[`initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) and [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). Both functions take similar arguments, except the `CustomEvent` allows you to pass-in a `detail` argument as an option. This can be used to send data to a receiving event listener.

```js
const helloEl = document.querySelector('#hello');

const dispatchLegacyEvent = (eventName, element = document, options = {}) => {
  const { bubbles = false, cancelable = false } = options;
  const createdEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
  createdEvent.initEvent(eventName, bubbles, cancelable);
  element.dispatchEvent(createdEvent);
};

const dispatchCustomEvent = (eventName, element = document, options = {}) => {
  const event = new CustomEvent(eventName, {
    bubbles: options.bubbles ?? false,
    cancelable: options.cancelable ?? false,
    detail: options.detail
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
};

helloEl.addEventListener('my-action', (e) => {
  if (e.detail) {
    console.log(`Ran ${e.detail} action!`);
  } else {
    console.log('Ran legacy action!');
  }
});

dispatchLegacyEvent('my-action', helloEl);
dispatchCustomEvent('my-action', helloEl, { detail: 'custom' });
```

```html
<div id="hello">Hello World</div>
```

**Note:** There are [40 more (not deprecated) event interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#interfaces_based_on_event) based on [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).